# Como controlar el tiempo dentro de un formulario sin realizar ninguna accion

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session

Buen dia comunidad,

Estoy realizando un formulario de gestion de casos en ASP.NET, el cual consta de una grilla(asp:gridview) de casos que los usuarios gestionan, el cual redirige a un formulario, si un usuario esta en el formulario de uno de todos los casos, ningun otro puede acceder .... eso lo podria controlar con una variable de application que se se setee cuando el usuario ingresa y validarla posteriormente si algun otro usuario quiere ingresar, pero como validar si el usuario en gestion no esta realizando ninguna accion o cerro el navegador ? existe una variable de application que expire cada cierto tiempo ?

Answer (score 0):

Buenas,

Una posible solución sería almacenar la información de en qué registro se encuentra el usuario en una variable de sesión. Después, en el fichero global.asax defines un método para limpiar la base de datos en caso de que termine la sesión:

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Lógica para limpiar la sesión
    LimpiarRegistro(Session["IdRegistro"]);
}
```

Otra cosa que podrías hacer es poner una marca de tiempo en el registro que se está editando para indicar cuándo ha entrado un usuario. Cuando entre otro usuario a editarlo, compruebas la marca de tiempo y si han pasado más de X minutos, podrías considerar que el primer usuario ha abandonado la página.

En mi opinión, esta segunda solución sería más robusta, ya que te evita problemas en caso de que se produzca un reinicio del pool de aplicaciones o cualquier otro de este tipo